# How to differentiate UI controls between O365 and Outlook?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

How can I define different UI controls and text for the same add-in between Office 365 (online) and Outlook (native on your machine)?

For example on Office 365 online we want the add-in button to be in a new dropdown, on Outlook in a new button group.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This cannot be done. Manifest's controls description doesn't have any Attributes/Tags to specify target host.

Comment: right, i just realised that. it's just unfortunate that both behave a bit differently based on the same manifest. for example the icons in the menu control only appear on outlook native (local), but not on office 365 (online).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael Heuberger currently, there's no way to define different UI controls and text (labels) for the same add-in between the Outlook Web App and the native Outlook Desktop client. Kindly submit a feature request to our UserVoice page : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Answer (score -1):

You could have two different views in your Add-in - one for Web and one for desktop. To achieve this define a following jQuery function:

```
function detectPlatform(platform) {
   if (platform == "OfficeOnline") {
      $('#WebView').removeClass('display-none').addClass('display-block');
      $('#DesktopView').removeClass('display-block').addClass('display-none');
   }
   else {
      $('#DesktopView').removeClass('display-none').addClass('display-block');
      $('#WebView').removeClass('display-block').addClass('display-none');
   }
}
```

and call it inside `$(document).ready` of `Office.initialize` like: `detectPlatform(Office.context.platform);`

In your HTML you could have 2 div containers with different UI elements:

```
<div id="WebView">Web UI</div>
<div id="DesktopView">Desktop UI</div>
```

Obviously you also have to define used CSS classes (`display:none` and `display:block`). If you don't want to use jQuery you can achieve the same with pure JS of course.

Comment: The OP is asking about ribbon controls which defined by add-on manifest file. Nothing to do with JS code.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, It was not specified in the question if its about Ribbon UI elements or UI elements that developer can create in his add-in. I was trying to help and I see no point in voting down this.

Comment: I understand and respect your time to help. Would you feel better if I tell you I just wrote the comment and didn't vote on your post at all? Please be positive and keep up adding your valuable input into community. The voting results are just for showing you that someone disagree with your solution, that's it. Nothing personal at all.  All the best.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov, sure thing.